# Can we disable the Video in the Programmable Video API - P2P connection - Twilio

Tags: javascript, node.js, twilio, p2p

Is it possible to have an audio call using the programmable video API of Twilio, using the P2P connection?
We would like to have both audio calls and video calls using the Programmable Video API and the P2P connection. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Yes you can disable the video stream. To do so, you need to pass the media options to `Video.connect` like so:

```js
Video.connect(token, { video: false, audio: true })
```

[The options you can pass to `connect` are documented here](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/video/releases/1.19.2/docs/global.html#ConnectOptions).

Let me know if that helps at all.